# Get order of sql server tables related to their relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, relationship, relation

is it possible to get an order of the tables in the SQL Server related to their relationships?

I thought, when i create insert Scrips, the ssms would set an order to the insert scripts. But they will be created alphabetically to the tablenames.

My Problem is, that i have to right an Import mechanism, to Import data. Now i have to know, with which tables i can begin and what tables has to be done before i can Import the next data.

In case of 200 tables it is a bit heavy to get an overview.

Maybe someone has an idea.

Thanks

David

Comment: No, that is something you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to be much better off using a tool that was designed to do a job like this, especially with a DB that has 200 tables. There are some free tools that can do this. One that comes to mind is SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools). It does schema and data comparisons. I use this all the time. It knows how to properly order the changes so you don't get FK errors etc.

Red Gate makes very good commercial tools that do schema and data comparisons. But they are a tad pricey. Personally, unless you really want to write your own solution, I'd check into with something like SSDT. You're going to save yourself a lot of grief.

Comment: the problem is, that we have a lot of changes on primary key site. So i cant use the SSDT. We're using SSDT to update the database. But in that case of migration, we'll have to change old primary keys from foxpro into new guid primary keys in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to encapsulate your sql statements with:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all'
GO

<your sql statements here>

EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1='ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all'
go
```

If you know exactly what you are doing ...